# How can I print the content of a map containing a set?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, output, stdmap

I have a map declared as follows:

```
map < string, set<string> > index;
std::map < string, set<string> >::iterator iter;
```

I would like to print the content of `index`. Therefore, I wrote the following:

```
for (iter = index.begin(); iter!= index.end(); iter++){
    cout << iter->first << endl;}  // It's OK.
```

But the code above doesn't work if I try to print `iter->second`:

```
for (iter = index.begin(); iter!= index.end(); iter++){
    cout << iter-> second << endl;}  // Doesn't work.
```

I suppose that is because `second` in `index` is a set of strings and not a simple string. But how can I can I print it?

Comment: You might be looking for `std::multimap<string, string>`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print

```
iter->second
```

using operator <<, you have to override this operator! Otherwise, iterate on set of string rappresented by  iter->second using a set iterator:

```
set<string>::iterator iterator_;
```

## update [iterator]

iterating is easy, ninja solution is overloading operator! :P

Iterating:

```
map<string, set<string> >::iterator iter_;
for (iter_ = index_.begin(); iter_ != index_.end(); iter_++) {
cout << iter_->first << " - ";
    set<string>::iterator iterator_;
for (iterator_ = s.begin(); iterator_ != s.end(); iterator_++) {
    cout << *iterator_ << " - ";
}   
    cout << endl;
}
```

## update [overloading ostream& opeartor<<]

```
class MySet: public set<string> {
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MySet& s) {
    set<string>::iterator iterator_;
    for (iterator_ = s.begin(); iterator_ != s.end(); iterator_++) {
        out << *iterator_;
    }
    return out;
}

void test() {
    map<string, MySet> index_;
    map<string, MySet>::iterator iter_;
    for (iter_ = index_.begin(); iter_ != index_.end(); iter_++) {
        cout << iter_->first << " - ";
        cout << iter_->second;  
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to iterate just using your suggestion.

Comment: Have you try? I also post second method!

Comment: Keep in mind that this `operator<<` will only be found from its own namespace, whereas all the other `operator<<` can be found from any namespace via argument-dependent lookup. ADL adds only `namespace std` to the search.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following function for the last few years. You have to be careful if you overload operator<<, as you can end up with the compiler giving you errors as it can't choose between the standard operator<< and your customised operator<<.

With C++11 introducing lambdas and range-based for loops, i'll probably need it less often.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<typename C>
void print_container(ostream& os, const C& c)
{
  copy(c.begin(), c.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
}

int main(void)
{
  vector<int> v; 
  v.push_back(1); 
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);

  print_container(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is (in my opinion) the single most annoying thing in C++ that the output operators are not defined for standard library types.

You need to some code a bit like:

```
typedef std::map < string, set<string> >::iterator iter;

for (iter = index.begin(); iter!= index.end(); iter++) {
  std::cout << iter->first << " : {";
  for(set<string>::iterator it = iter->second.begin(); it != iter->second.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `iter->second` represents a set of strings in your code. You cannot simply print it, because `operator<<` of the output stream does not know how to format a `std::set` by default. As explained in *Luca Davanzo's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704024/2675154), one solution is to overload that operator for your set.

Another solution, as shown in *Chris Jefferson's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704346/2675154), is to simply add another loop for iterating over your set. However, the readability of that solution can be improved by using the following [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) features: [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and the placeholder [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). As a result, your code could look as short follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> index;
index["a"] = { "v", "w" };
index["b"] = { "x", "y", "z" };

for (const auto &mapItem : index) {
    std::cout << "m[" << mapItem.first << "] =";
    for (const auto &setItem : mapItem.second)
        std::cout << " " << setItem;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> m[a] = v w
>   m[b] = x y z

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) you can use range-based for loops together with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). This improves readability even further, as you can remove the `first` and `second` members from your code:

```
for (const auto &[k, v] : index) {
    std::cout << "m[" << k << "] =";
    for (const auto &s : v)
        std::cout << " " << s;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05e92a44060f567d)